# How to prevent selenium from opening new firefox windows?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am running Selenium Firefox Webdriver on Python for webscraping and when I am going around diferent pages, some of those have some mechanism that open new windows, something in the way of this:

```
$(function(){ 
    window.open(url, windowName[, windowFeatures]); 
});
```

And it is some kind of malicious webpage that keeps opening random pages on new windows and after some minutes my PC runs out of memory and crashes.

So want I want is to load some feature on the webdriver so it doesn't allow pages to open new windows.

I have tryed not to load JS but this feature is no longer working I guess.
Also, if you know some option or preference to ignore script tags I would like to know it.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading a JS file just in your tests which overwrites the window.open function. Something like:

```
(function(){
    window.open = function() { return false; }
})();
```

Notice this is an [immediatly invoked function exectution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).